# Why IFrame does not display its content(google maps) in gmail using HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, iframe, gmail

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwLW0.png]
Why IFrame does not display its content(google maps) in gmail using HTML?
When im trying to send an invoice html format report it contains google maps within iframe but does not showing up.

Comment: Did it show up if you use a Browser?  Provide some relevant code.

Comment: HI Jeroen Heier thanks for your reply.. Code: <iframe src=https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m28!1m12!1m3!1d62182.22305523122!2d80.1731242364963!3d13.074518899305058!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m13!3e6!4m5!1s0x3a5263ba9a487b3f%3A0x1e923f00f5206296!2sAmbattur%2C+Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu+600053%2C+India!3m2!1d13.1143167!2d80.1480551!4m5!1s0x3a52662d447bf903%3A0x59459a3f125af1da!2sMylapore%2C+Chennai%2C+Tamil+Nadu%2C+India!3m2!1d13.0367914!2d80.2676303!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1460378912380&output=embed></iframe>
Note: It showing in Browser but not in gmail and other mail clients

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/467981/Html-IFrame-tag-is-not-being-interpret-in-email-bo) explanation.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen now i'm clear about IFrame... is there any other solution to send a google maps with html mail #researching @Jeroen